# How do I make two divs have the same height no matter the content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[What I am trying to edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw8Fa.png)

Originally I had the min-width and a max-width of both of them to be the same but when I changed the image in the left one, there was an overflow so I took out the max-width property. I also tried using the flex-grow property but it didn't work. Is there any other way I can achieve what I want?

```css
#section_body_6.main.container {
  padding-top: 6vw;
  /* padding-right: 3vw; */
  padding-bottom: 6vw;
  /* padding-left: 3vw; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(43, 48, 71, 0.4), rgba(43, 48, 71, 0.4)), url("/pix_builder/elements/images/makeup/1.png") fixed no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner {
  height: 100%;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner .widget {
  padding: 1vw;
}

#section_body_6.main .width {
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.image {
  padding: 1vw;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 45%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 600px;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.image .logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.image .main {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #f7a885;
  padding-top: 2vw;
  padding-right: 3vw;
  padding-left: 3vw;
  width: 55%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 600px;
  max-height: 600px;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text h1 {
  font-size: 56px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup .sign {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup .form {
  width: 70%;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup input {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  color: #020020;
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: inherit;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  margin: 1vw;
}

#section_body_6.main .inner.text .signup button {
  background: #2b3047;
  color: #ffffff;
  align-items: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  transition: color 0.2s linear, background 0.2s linear, border-color 0.2s linear, text-shadow 0.2s linear;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 48px;
  min-width: 96px;
  padding: 14px 24px;
  font-family: "Karla", sans-serif;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section id="section_body_6" class="main container">
  <div class="width">
    <div class="inner image">
      <div class="widget">
        <img class="logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uO-2GwlFxWnex3obmZmPi4xmZgdXofKigjih4aH_tmKswH-x56GfWFTB82Yquc6fJhWmNVwoCSDSjgH705-XWnQ=s0" data-image-upload-source="builder3" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px">
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <img class="main" src="/pix_builder/elements/images/makeup/5.png" data-src="/pix_builder/elements/images/makeup/5.png" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner text">
      <div class="widget">
        <h1>Look and Feel Perfect Every Day.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <p>
          Subscribe to my newsletter to get my FREE Every Day Makeup Look guide, PLUS top secret tips and tricks used by the industry’s leading makeup artists.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="signup">
        <div class="widget">
          <img class="lp-image-react w-8cdb4d98-8e02-3986-a823-950a991fde05 css-1cg3cc6 sign" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dmY1Sjs5FSKW-wkI-McMrvHbxsIIzeKI38qUb20rnpXb_llEPPoCudG3xhzuYB12sCn8DpRM_GnUUjCMjsDMiw=s0" data-image-upload-source="builder3" alt=""
            style="width:100%;max-width:200px">
        </div>
        <div class="widget form">
          <form action="#" method="get" target="_top">
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit" onclick="popup()">Sign-Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what i found, u have class **#section_body_6.main .inner.image .main** in which u provide **max-width: 300px;** but **height** changed automaticaly, solution:

```css
#section_body_6.main.container{
    padding-top: 6vw;
    /* padding-right: 3vw; */
    padding-bottom: 6vw;
    /* padding-left: 3vw; */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(43, 48, 71, 0.4), rgba(43, 48, 71, 0.4)), url("/pix_builder/elements/images/makeup/1.png") fixed no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
}
#section_body_6.main .inner{
    height: 100%;
}
#section_body_6.main .inner .widget{
    padding: 1vw;
}
#section_body_6.main .width{
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
#section_body_6.main .inner.image{
    padding: 1vw;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 45%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 600px;
}
#section_body_6.main .inner.image .logo{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px
}
#section_body_6.main .inner.image .main{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 390px;
}
#section_body_6.main .inner.text{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #f7a885;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    padding-right: 3vw;
    padding-left: 3vw;
    width: 55%;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<section id="section_body_6" class="main container">
  <div class="width">
    <div class="inner image">
      <div class="widget">
        <img class="logo" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/uO-2GwlFxWnex3obmZmPi4xmZgdXofKigjih4aH_tmKswH-x56GfWFTB82Yquc6fJhWmNVwoCSDSjgH705-XWnQ=s0" data-image-upload-source="builder3" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:150px">
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <img class="main" src="https://www.fabmood.com/inspiration/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/eye-makeup-looks.jpg" data-src="/pix_builder/elements/images/makeup/5.png" alt="" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner text">
      <div class="widget">
        <h1>Look and Feel Perfect Every Day.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="widget">
        <p>
          Subscribe to my newsletter to get my FREE Every Day Makeup Look guide, PLUS top secret tips and tricks used by the industry’s leading makeup artists.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="signup">
        <div class="widget">
          <img class="lp-image-react w-8cdb4d98-8e02-3986-a823-950a991fde05 css-1cg3cc6 sign" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/dmY1Sjs5FSKW-wkI-McMrvHbxsIIzeKI38qUb20rnpXb_llEPPoCudG3xhzuYB12sCn8DpRM_GnUUjCMjsDMiw=s0" data-image-upload-source="builder3" alt="" style="width:100%;max-width:200px">
        </div>
        <div class="widget form">
          <form action="#" method="get" target="_top">
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            <button type="submit" onclick="popup()">Sign-Up</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

one method of doing this is adding `display: flex` to their parent

Comment: minimum code would be helpful

Comment: from what i see on the image it seems that there is either `padding` or `margin` around the button

Comment: there is
I've added the code

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 